# SQL Server report generation with SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

Can SSRS be automated to export the same report with varying criteria?

The use-case is, I have a report template and want to export a copy of this report for each sales person (the filter criteria).  Don't want to automatically email it or have a person setup the subscription, just export x number of reports for x number of sales reps.

Comment: If you don't mean email, then what do you mean by "export" the report?

Comment: Subscriptions are how you "automate" running a report.  Each subscription can have its own filter settings and can save to a network share (at least with some editions of SSRS).  You can set up the subscriptions for others (they don't **have** to do it themselves).  Please clarify what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Let's assume I have 1000 sales people and I want a copy of the report saved for each to a network share.  Does this mean setting up 1000 subscriptions?  Can the number of reports and criteria be determined from a datastore (so we don't have to maintain all these subscriptions as sales reps come and go)?

Comment: @Christopherous5000 - Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin 2008 R2 Ent

Answer (score 1):

A subscription (where a user or group receives the report by email or file share)  has to have preselected criteria. For the user to select criteria then they have to run the SSRS interface (IE client) and select from the dropdowns or enter selection criteria in an input box.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Data-Driven Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx).
Note that is supported by the following editions of SQL Server:

- Up to SQL Server 2008R2: **DataCenter** and **Enterprise**
- SQL Server 2012+: **Business Intelligence** and **Enterprise**

---

If you don't have one of these editions of SQL Server, you could still develop a small application to do this process:

- Get the sales people
- For every people, generate a report

You would have to consume the [Report Server Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx).
The [Render method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx#M:ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService.Render%28System.String,System.String,System.String@,System.String@,System.String@,ReportExecution2005.Warning[]@,System.String[]@%29) is what you will be looking for.

Comment: This looks promising, will give it a go.